# How do you access ratnet?

Tags: beglitched

[image]

This network features four nodes, all empty. I tried to log into each of those individually, but zilch. I tried to spend (waste?) all of my money and logging in again, but still nothing. Clicking on the money counter does nothing. Warping from left to right costs money, but it also achieves nothing. Scanning at every step does nothing. Applying ice does nothing. The money spending method not pictured, Firewall, also does nothing.

What do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this has nothing to do with money.

You need to first complete the (rather dreadful) puzzles in eggnet. Doing so will unlock the Egg network scrambler. Give ratnet a scramble, and voilà! An exit.

[image]